# logging options for all file move operations in linux

Tags: logging

I'm curious if anyone has a suggestion to log only file move operations specifying the source and destination of the move.

I believe auditd has some functionality here, but I'm trying to stay away from maintaining a db to track changes, as the fs I want this on is rather large.

Auditd may be an option if there's a way I can add new files to the db upon creation without having to scan the fs and rebuild the db.

Thanks,
M

Answer (score 0):

inotify-tools appears to address the issue, e.g.,:

```
# recursively wait on directory for any events where files are moved to it 
inotifywait -m -r -e moved_to /root/notify/test1 | 
 while read f; do                                   # when an event occurs
  LOC=`echo $f | awk '{print $1$3}'`                # construct the new path to file
  GRP=`stat -c "%G" $(echo $f | awk '{print $1}')`  # query the parent folders group
  chgrp -Rv "$GRP" "$LOC" && 
   echo "success for grp change on $GRP for $LOC"   # change group ownership of object to parent
 done
```

source : https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools